# Joining all matches of a group in VIM

Tags: regular-expression, vim, replace

I'm trying to write a replacement command that would search for a text containing at least 4 letters separated by spaces and remove the spaces:

```
%s/\v%(([a-zA-Z])\s){3,}([a-zA-Z])/\1\2/gc
```

But

```
L i g ht
```

becomes

```
ght
```

as expected because a group contains only the last match which was `g` in that case. How to accumulate all the matches of group `\1` and then join them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a repeated group like `(...){n,m}` or `(...)+`, I don't think there's any way in to Vim extract each occurrence of the group. Only the last is made available in all regex-related functions and commands.

That said, you can use a nested substitution:

```
:s/\v%([a-zA-Z]\s){3,}[a-zA-Z]/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\s', '', 'g')/gc
```

A `\=` in the replacement of `:s` makes Vim evaluate the replacement as an expression. And in that expression, I'm using the [`substitute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) function to remove all spaces in the entire matched text of `:s` (obtained by [`submatch(0)`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#submatch%28%29)), giving `Ligh` from `L i g h`.

Comment: Thanks. I also thought about removal of spaces in the whole match as a workaround but still hoped it were possible to join all the matches of a group... Please, append 'gc' at the end. I also wanted to confirm the replacement. That was crucial.

Comment: @ka3ak done. There's also a [vi.se] Stack Exchange for Vim, if you're interested